# Updating textbox with certain ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtExp " runat="server" CssClass="dtext costlmw" Width="200px" onkeypress="return false" autocomplete="off" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtExpID" runat="server" CssClass="dtext costlmw" Width="200px" onkeypress="return false" autocomplete="off" />
```

i have two text boxes, one has id txtExp and the other is txtExmpID

```
 $("input[id*='txtExp']").val(sum.toFixed(2));
```

the line above updates BOTH textboxes with the value `sum`

i guess `*` means "contains"? but i thought that's what `~` means?

```
  $("input[~id='txtExp']").val(sum.toFixed(2));
```

i've also tried

```
   $("input[id='txtExp']").val(sum.toFixed(2));
```

when then nothing happens at all.

Comment: Could you post the rendered html?

Answer (score 4):

Use the ID selector `#`

```
$("#txtExp").val(x);
```

ASP.NET renders your ID's differently -- Either use the `ClientID` property, set the `ClientIDMode`, or just use a `.` and target the class.

Comment: it's coming up as "undefined" when i do it that way

Comment: ASP.NET is the culprit! If your JS is in the .aspx file, do `$("#<%= txtExp.ClientID %>").val(x);`

Answer (score 0):

`*=` mean the value of the attribute contains the specified word. `~=` mean the value of the attribute is sliced into whitespace separated words, and the specified word matches one of those whitespace separated word exactly.

Also `~id="xxxx"` is a wrong syntax.